# How do you unit test Angular module bundling?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

First of all, should I unit test the following piece of code?

```
angular.module('thirdPartyDeps', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router'
]);

angular.module('core', [
    'core.endpoints',
    'core.AppInitializer',
    'core.AppStatus'
]);

angular.module('myApp', [
    'app.config',
    'app.routes',
    'app.run',
    'thirdPartyDeps',
    'core',
]);
```

All it does is bundle modules into the main `myApp` module.
If the answer is YES, then how do you unit test that?

**EDIT:**
I'm not looking to test that `angular.module` works.
I'm asking if testing a correct configuration (e.g. all modules are being loaded) is worth it. While the app will fail at runtime with a wrong configuration, unit tests would discover this issue at build time, so before it reaches an environment where to break.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, no, you should not unit test this code, because all you are doing is running the built-in angular code, which has already been tested by the Angular authors (one would assume) and isn't your own code.

The only thing you can do wrong here is enter a module name incorrectly, in which case Angular will throw a clear [nomod error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod) at startup on your actual page, and nothing will work, so it will be pretty obvious something isn't right and how to fix it.

Unit/Integration tests are generally most useful for testing business logic and component interaction, of which this is neither.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking to unit test correct configuration rather than Angular doing its job. So, the build would fail if all of the modules weren't defined, as opposed to build working then seeing the app doesn't start.